# Jquery Colorpicker show value in inputfield

Tags: jquery, input, color-picker

I use this colorpicker plugin:http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

How can i show the start value in the inputfield?

Here is a JSFiddle what i have: http://jsfiddle.net/z6Ddy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use attr to set a value

```
$('#colorSelector input').attr('value', '#' + hex);
```

Instead use

```
$('#colorSelector input').val('#' + hex);
```

Comment: Oke, but still users not see the hexcode in the inputfield when you not have change the picker... How i can do that?

Comment: See the example the hexcode does show up however your color picker is a bit messed up as you have to click and drag around

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you'll store the value in a database for use later. If so, you'll want to use whatever scripting language of your choice to populate the text input, the background of the div that shows the color, and the color attribute of the Color Picker initialization.

So basically, you'll check to see if there's a value set in the database, and if so, insert the hex value into the background-color property of the div style, and value attribute of the text input, and the "color" property of the color picker initialization.

If no value is set, you can set a default, say "#FF0000."

[I updated the fiddle,](http://jsfiddle.net/z6Ddy/3/) adding comments where you would insert data via a script or ajax, but your question is more PHP or .NET centric I think than jQuery and Color-picker.